# Render Highcharts in dynamic iFrame

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am trying to render Highcharts in a div dynamically created inside iFrame.

The html part:

```
<div id="fr">Get iframe</div>
<div id="ch9">
<div id="chart3"> chart2</div>
</div>
<p><iframe id="ifr"></iframe></p>
```

The jQuery part:

1. Create an div inside the iframe:

   ```
   var iframeContent;
    $(function () {
            $("#fr").click(function () {
                $('#ifr').contents().find('body').html($('#ch9').html());
                iframeContent = $('#ifr').contents().find('#ch3');
            });
   ```
2. Try to load a Highchart into iframeContent element (a fragment of the code):

   ```
   .....
   chart2= new Highcharts.Chart({
           chart: {
       renderTo:iframeContent,
               type: 'spline',
   ......
   ```

But it doesn't work and throws an error

```
Object has no method setAttribute
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call script on elements inside wrapped elements by iframe. You have no access to this element.

Answer (score -1):

pass the id to

`renderTo : 'containerId'`

if you want to use a object then extract its id by `iframeContent[0]` or extract its id and then pass it to the chart.

EDIT: another example.

if you are using highcharts 3.* you can go with $("#container").highcharts({}); here it is equivalent to iframeContent..highcharts({});

Comment: Isn't it exactly what I am doing? 1. get the element as object: iframeContent = $('#ifr').contents().find('#ch3'); 2. render chart - renderTo:iframeContent. What is wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: iframeContent.highcharts({}); doesn't work if the element is inside of iFrame. It works only if the element is in the same window.